# How to push and pop scenes properly in Cocos2D v3.x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I push a preloaded scene B onto scene A like this. The root node in the scene B has an animation that runs for ~2 seconds, and I want scene B to be popped when the animation is done. I think it should work like below. However it crashes on popScene. Does push/pop really work in Cocos2D v3?

```
SceneRedroom* sceneredroom = (SceneRedroom*)[self.ccscenewithSceneredroom getChildByName:@"SceneRedroom" recursively:NO];
[sceneredroom.animationManager setCompletedAnimationCallbackBlock:^(id sender) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
}];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:self.ccscenewithSceneredroom];
```

The crashes I get are fairly random. It seems like some things are incorrectly deallocated or similar when pushing and/or popping scenes.

Comment: If you get a crash post the crash message (last lines in the log), call stack and offending code. Add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: The crashes were too random and thus the crash messages, but generally  they were misfired messages going to incorrect objects - that's why I suspect some deallocations for some reason happen to early... anyway, I don't really have time to create some test case and reverted to not using another scene for displaying cutscenes, I just add another CCNode to existing scene hierarchy.

Comment: Try not to call `popScene()` in AnimationCallback, instead call `popScene()` 1 frame after that.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I managed to find a solution to the problem I was having through this post. I removed the CCDirector pause and resume in my pauseGame and resumeGame methods then added this:

```
//pause
[sprite.actionManager pauseTarget:sprite];

//resume
[sprite.actionManager resumeTarget:sprite];
```

This stopped the animation and kept the "paused" state even if the game is closed then reopened and I didn't even need to play with the AppDelegate class :). I hope this helps others too.

UPDATE: Just in case anybody else is creating a sprite using a loop, here's how I managed to create the pause and resume function for it:

```
[sprite.actionManager pauseAllRunningActions];
[sprite.actionManager resumeTargets:[NSSet setWithArray:spriteArray]];
```

note the difference between the two (resumeTarget and resumeTargets) then since resumeTargets would ask for NSSet, I simply passed the array objects into a NSSet with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
void PauseScene::goToMainMenuScene(cocos2d::Ref *sender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->resume();
    auto scene = MainMenuScene::createScene();
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(TRANSITION_TIME, scene));
}

void PauseScene::resumeScene(cocos2d::Ref *sender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->popScene();
}

void PauseScene::restartScene(cocos2d::Ref *sender)
{
    Director::getInstance()->resume();
    auto scene = GameScene::createScene();
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(TransitionFade::create(TRANSITION_TIME, scene));
}
```